# Compile time type tracing

Tags: scala, metaprogramming

Is it possible to add some magic construct around a Scala expression so that it prints the type during compilation? E.g. have some class, magic function, meta programming type, which does:

```
val i = 1
Some(11).map(Trace(_ + 1))

// compile
// prints: Int
```

Comment: Are you sure you want it to print `Int` and not `Option[Int]`?

Comment: Yes, the type of `_ + 1` should be `Int`.

Comment: Looks to me like a candidate for an annotation plus compiler plugin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not exactly, but how 'bout this

```
$ cat Test.scala
def Trace[T] = identity[T] _

val i = 1
Some(11) map {x => Trace(x + 1)}



$ scala -Xprint:typer Test.scala 2>&1 | egrep --o 'Trace\[.*\]'
Trace[T >: Nothing <: Any]
Trace[Int]
```

The first Trace comes from the definition of Trace and can be ignored.  The same parameter (-Xprint:typer) works with scalac, too.

Comment: Too bad it doesn’t work in a case like `Some("11").map {x => Trace(x) / 1}` (though it works for some other erroneous code); but it seems to be the best we can get.

Answer (score 4):

If things get really nasty, you can use this:

```
scala -Xprint:typer -Xprint-types
```

Gets difficult to read, but tells you exactly what the compiler is thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work at **runtime**

```
def Type[T](x:T):T = {println(x.asInstanceOf[AnyRef].getClass()); x }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no such thing. A compiler plugin might be able to do it.