# Debuggin single lines in Scala

Tags: eclipse, debugging, scala, scala-ide

A single of code can achieve a lot in Scala.

```
def -(that: Nat) = if (that.isZero) this else throw new Error("negative number")
```

However, it is difficult to debug.
Any tips?

Answer (score 4):

Use [scala worksheet](https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-worksheet/wiki/Getting-Started). That's it: you'll get multiline REPL with your environment in which you can play with your code.

[image]
Alternatively, just use REPL bundled with sbt (`sbt console`) with proper imports

Comment: Thanks but what about for tonnes of existing code that is in scala objects / classes?

Comment: @MoreThanFive nothing special: use debugger & logging output, just like usually.

Answer (score -1):

you can see output of compiler phases, i.e. the AST after desugarings with

> scalac -Xprint:typer
>
> scalac -Xprint-types  (note hyphen, not colon)

The man page is a little confusing, there's no "typer" phase listed, but it works:

http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/tools/scalac.html

[Compile time type tracing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992456/compile-time-type-tracing)